# Media query making element behave strange

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I've got this bug which is driving me to insanity. Basically I've got two buttons side-by-side, and when I re-size down to mobile screens and then back up the buttons are no longer side-by-side. Instead they act as if one of the buttons are no longer floated. When I check the console the element has gotten the float property back but it hasn't actually been applied so that the buttons appear side-by-side..

Does anyone know what might be causing this? And how on earth do I fix it? Been playing around with it for hours with no luck.

**EDIT:** Managed to recreate the bug: http://plnkr.co/edit/mbo2f0Xg9lkGou9sx8jl?p=preview

```
#topics-button-wrapper {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }

    > button {

        &:first-of-type {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        &:last-of-type {
            float: right;

            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                float: none; //Seem to be keeping this even though it applies 'float: right'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The markup:

```
<span class="main-topic">
    <a ng-href="#/{{topic.name}}" ng-bind="topic.name"></a>
    <div class="clear-fix" id="topics-button-wrapper">
        <button data-my-new-topic-slide class="bg-delay button filled round narrow-button">New topic</button>
        <button class="button plain round narrow-button">Statistics</button>
    </div>
</span>
```

## Desktop before bug occurs:

[image: desktop before bug]

## Look in smaller screens:

[image: smaller screens]

## Desktop after re-sizing back to full screen:

[image: desktop after bug]

Comment: add Less-css to your question tags please and give us a link to the website

Comment: @knitevision It's the same with and without it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I mean mate, if you have this metatag, just forget this bug. Because no one apart from a developer will be able to reproduce it. Because users will not be able to zoom in/out the app. But if you are curious about why this happens, you need to recreate your bug so as we could have a look

Comment: @Chrillewoodz "animals" lacks. Can't reproduce - http://codepen.io/knitevision1/full/xbzyVz

Comment: @knitevision I'm having trouble re-producing it myself.. It's so strange. If I can reproduce it on a normal desktop by just changing window size then surely users will be able to do the same? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz you miss something. Users do not tend to resize the window to 600px then back to full screen. That's what you miss.

Comment: @knitevision I do it all the time even when I'm not developing. Surely I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz please create a jsfiddle/codepen example that 100% resembles your code logics.

Comment: @knitevision http://plnkr.co/edit/mbo2f0Xg9lkGou9sx8jl?p=preview, run it when the plunkr preview screen is big and you will see my problem. :)

Comment: @ZeRubeus No, the appropriate action is to provide only the compiled CSS if it is a pure CSS problem, and never provide the uncompiled version.

Comment: @cimmanon Provided fully compiled css in Plunkr. Have a look.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Not interested in looking at Plunkr, it is broken in some browsers (namely, the only one I care to use)

Comment: @cimmanon you can see the deleted post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option #1**, remove `.clear-fix:after` from `#topics-button-wrapper`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSd5T5YAjzWcd5RecepU?p=preview)

**Option #2**, remove `floats` from buttons

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Twt5HQpLhMVrLT2QEZT?p=preview)

**Option #3**, remove `.clear-fix:after` and add `overflow: hidden;`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TMVuMN6qyyr4upc2T2vg?p=preview)

**Option #4**, add `display: block;` and `overflow: hidden;` to `.main-topic`

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWbcEUglYM6M3HRz85iU?p=preview)

Comment: Please do not upvote that I beg of you. Just accept that as an answer (if those are vital options and move on)

Comment: Nr 4 doesn't work just so you know. Nr 1 did fix this issue though, even though I can't figure out why it caused a problem. And I must say thank you for taking the time to investigate. Appreciate it.